# Double to Time Format VBA

Tags: vba, time, format, double

At the begging I want tell you that I just read a lot of stack's about it and I didnt find solution so...

I'm substracting two dates
1 - 2017/05/05 17:00
2 - 2017/05/09 18:00

I want to receive "4 Days 1 Hour"
How I should do it? I tried to use DateFormat/Format/DateDiff and a lot of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't always have to be a ready-made VBA function. Especially with dates, I *rarely* find what I want exactly as VBA-ready. Try this custom function:

```
Function myDateDiff(ByVal d1 As Date, ByVal d2 As Date) As String
  Dim days As Long, hours As Long
  days = DateDiff("d", d1, d2)               ' diff in days
  hours = DateDiff("h", d1, d2) - days * 24  ' diff in hours
  myDateDiff = days & " Day" & IIf(days > 1, "s ", " ") & hours & " Hour" & IIf(hours > 1, "s", "")
End Function
```

---

```
Sub Test()
    Dim d1 As Date, d2 As Date
    d1 = CDate("2017/05/05 17:00")
    d2 = CDate("2017/05/09 18:00")
    Debug.Print myDateDiff(d1, d2)    ' 4 Days 1 Hour

    d1 = CDate("2017/05/05 17:00")
    d2 = CDate("2017/05/06 19:00")
    Debug.Print myDateDiff(d1, d2)    ' 1 Day 2 Hours
End Sub
```